# View not updating when model changed

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a single page UI, which looks like below .

on the UI there are two checkboxes, when user toggle the states of checkbox, I use ajax to post the status to HomeController in a POST action.

after updated the model in POST action with the new checkboxes states, I redirect back to GET action to return a view.

however, the UI does not refresh with the new model.

can someone help on this ? thanks.

```
Views/Home/Index.cshtml

    @{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

@model WebApplication5.Controllers.HomeModel;


<h1>STS</h1>
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="UseVersionCheckBox" />Use version v1 in url
</div>
<br />
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="ResponseTypeTokenCheckBox" /> Return access token in url
</div>

<div>your check status : @Model.IsChecked</div>
<br />
<div>your text : @Model.Text </div>

_Layout.cshtml

    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - WebApplication5</title>

</head>
<body>

    @RenderBody()
    <script src="~/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            function fun() {
                var current = $("#UseVersionCheckBox").prop("checked");
                var current2 = $("#ResponseTypeTokenCheckBox").prop("checked");

                alert("values as:" + current + "," + current2);

                var json = {};
                json.UseVersionChecked = current;
                json.ResponseTypeTokenChecked = current2;
                var text = JSON.stringify(json);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Home/Index",
                    data: text,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    error: function (r, s, e) {

                    },
                    success: function (r) {

                    },
                    complete: function () {

                    }
                });
            }

            $("#UseVersionCheckBox").click(fun);
            $("#ResponseTypeTokenCheckBox").click(fun);


        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>


HomeController.cs



public class HomeController : Controller
{


    public HomeController()
    {

    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeModel model;

        if (TempData.ContainsKey("model"))
        {
            var newmodel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HomeModel>(TempData["model"].ToString());

            model = newmodel;

        }
        else
        {
            model = new HomeModel();
            model.IsChecked = false;
            model.Text = "not checked";
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index([FromBody] CheckStatus status)
    {
        HomeModel model = new HomeModel();

        model.IsChecked = true;
        model.Text = "UseVersionCheckBox : " + status.UseVersionChecked + " ; ResponseTypeTokenCheckbox : " + status.ResponseTypeTokenChecked;

        if (TempData.ContainsKey("model"))
            TempData.Remove("model");

        TempData.Add("model", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));

        ModelState.Clear();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class HomeModel
{
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class CheckStatus
{
    public bool UseVersionChecked { get; set; }
    public bool ResponseTypeTokenChecked { get; set; }
}
```

weird thing , after checked the response of redirect to GET action, the new value is there ,but web page in browser still show old. why ?

Comment: the ModelState.Clear() does not work, the UI still shows the default value , even after the POST, the correct new model is created.

Comment: Because the whole point of ajax is to stay on the **SAME** page. Ajax calls never redirect. If you want to redirect DO NOT use ajax!